# Sbt publish-local use strange repo structure

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, ivy

I published jar with sbt to local ivy repo (`${$HOME}/.ivy2`).
Then i have changed the play config file such way, that play started to use default local ivy repo (the same `${$HOME}/.ivy2`). But play did not managed to find jar, that i published with sbt.
I think i fount out why this happend.

all other dependencies that play downloaded has structure like

```
ivy_home/cache/group_id/artifact_id/jars/artifact_id-version.jar
e.g. /home/maxim/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor/jars/akka-actor-2.0.1.jar
```

but jar, that i published with sbt is located in

```
ivy_home/local/group_id/artifact_id/version/jars/artifact_id.jar
e.g. /home/maxim/.ivy2/local/com.mkotolyov.test/server-core/1.1.1-SNAPSHOT/jars/server-core.jar
```

i googled, but didn't find how to config sbt to publish with "default" structure.

my project in Build.scala

```
lazy val core = Project(
    "server-core",
    file("core"),
    settings = buildSettings ++ Seq(
      publishTo := Some(myProxyMavenRepo),
      publishMavenStyle := true,
      publishArtifact in Test := false,

      pomIncludeRepository := {
        _ => false
      },
      resolvers := depResolvers,
      unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= baseDirectory( _ / "src" ),
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        config,
        sprayJson,
        scalatest,
        prettyTime,
        casbahCore, casbahCommons, casbahQuery,
        mysql, squeryl, postgresql,
        quartz
      )
    )
  )
```

I have the flag `publishMavenStyle := true` but it is targeted only for common `publish`, and not to `publish-local`. Any way i have tried to remove it - nothing changes.

Comment: Interesting. I have the same problem right now with 0.13.0, except that the structure that publish-local is creating is ~/.ivy2/local/groupId/artifactId/scalaVersion/sbtVersion/version. Resolver.defaultLocal doesn't solve it for me.

Comment: Er... Never mind. My problem was that I was trying to reference a plugin with libraryDependencies when I should have been using addSbtPlugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have added Resolver.defaultLocal to resovers list and play found my jar.

```
resolvers := depResolvers :+ Resolver.defaultLocal
```